Long black cave insect in Thailand
I encountered this strange insect in a cave in Thailand (Kaew in Sam Roi Yot, to be specific) a couple of weeks ago. Google and iNaturalist are failing me. I think it's about 3 inches long not counting the antennae. It didn't have a strong reaction to the light but did sink further into the crevices. 

No Idea. Thaibugs might be a place to start.

Current consensus on iNaturalist seems to be that it is some sort of whip scorpion. Cool!
What to me looked like the head and "eyes" in the above photo are the pedilaps being held tightly together in front of the actual head. If you look closely at the rear end, you can also see the "whip" folded forward reaching towards its head. I am unable to determine which species it is exactly (this one is more long and skinny than anything I can find examples of), but here is an example of a whip scorpion holding its pedilaps together in a similar fashion.

Welcome Jay. Link-only answers are considered to not be enough and may be deleted. If you're able to add details and then use the link in support of your answer then that would save your answer from that fate. See the [help] article how to write a good answer for guidance.

Could you at least mention some morphological feature seen in the photo that would indicate the plausibility? Do whip scorpions have "claws" in front? (example) I don't see any large appendages at either end of the specimen in the photo. Is the specimen facing up or down? Thanks!  (and Jimmy Cricket is correct; link-only answers where readers must go off-site to get any supporting information are strongly discouraged in Stack Exchange; an answer needs to retain value if and when the links break in the future)

Updated with more details, sorry guys!

Thanks for the edit, looks great! I saw it because I clicked "follow" under the question. In the future, if you want to reply to a specific user, see How do comment @replies work? found in FAQ.

Did you mean "pedipalps"?
